# Regex in Latex Document

Tags: regex, replace, latex

I am writing a paper in Latex and I just realized (after 20 pages) that I had not been stating which mathematical norms I am using. I use two types of norms `\| something \|_F` and `\| something \|_2`.

I have completely forgotten putting the 2 whenever I was using 2 norm and wrote `\| something \|` instead. My F norms are always explicit and correct.

Here is a sample of what the document looks like:

```
\| x+y \|_F &\leq \| x+y\| \\
&\leq \| x+z\| + \|z+y\| \\
.
.
.
\|x\| \leq \|y\|
.
.
.
\|x+2y+z\|^2 \leq \|d\|_F^2
```

**Question:**

I want to convert all of `\| something \|` to `\| something \|_2` without touching the `\| something \|_F`. How do I do that?

I don't even know where to start. I have never done find-replace using regex (or anything tool). I was thinking of just doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

So this may seem funky but this is what I came up with after some trial and error given your example:

```
\\\|(?!_F)((?:(?!\\\|).)*)\\\|(?!_F)
```

`\\` refers to a '\' character. The first \ is to escape from the regex character .

`\|` refers to a '|' character. The first \ is to escape from the regex character |.

`(?!_F)` excludes the string '_F' (this avoids matching _F at the beginning following an ending \| tag. It's also used at the end of the match to exclude the _F suffix.

`((?:(?!\\\\|).)*)` matches everything but the closing '\|' tag.

The matches I got running this regex were the second x+y, the x+z, the z+y, the x, the y, and the x+2y+z. So the two _F suffixes, the d and the first x+y are excluded.

Let me know if you have any questions!